# Slicing a 2D numpy array into a 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a 2D numpy array, `FilteredOutput`, that has 2 columns and 10001 rows, though the number of rows is a variable.

I am trying to take the 2nd column of `FilteredOutput` and use it to populate a new 1D numpy array called `timeSeriesArray` using [some code I found](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)):

```
timeSeriesArray = np.array(FilteredOutput[:,0])
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Why?

Comment: If you want the second column, you should probably use `[:,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved now.  The problem was that I had not explicitly declared FilteredOutput to be a numpy array inside the function.  I thought it had been declared as a numpy array outside the function, but the problem was solved when I added

```
FilteredOutput = np.array(FilteredOutput)
```

before

```
timeSeriesArray = np.array(FilteredOutput[:,0])
```

note: `numpy` is imported as `np`